# Is it necessay to update npm to update node?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to npm and node so pardon if my question is silly, but is it necessary to update npm to its latest version if i want to update Node.js to its latest version? I read the npm wikipedia page and it says npm is a `package manager` for `Node.js`. Also, does npm provide a runtime environment for Node appications to work?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is the runtime (using the V8 JavaScript engine). Yes, npm is a package manager that helps include dependencies in the program, but it is not the only one. There are others like yarn, so npm is not essential to Node.js. There are [several upgrade methods to choose from](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/), using all the same installation methods typically available on operating systems. npm does not offer Node.js upgrades directly; options include node *version* manager and the npm-installable module n:

```sh
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

None of the methods mention an npm update, though it is a good idea to keep npm current for security. If a given upgrade method does require you to have a certain version of some manager or installer, you will get a message about it when trying to upgrade.